# Saving OAuth2 credentials to database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, authentication, sqlalchemy

I'm writing web application that uses [Google Proximity Beacon API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides) to interact with beacon data. In order to access that data, I need to grant access to use beacons' information for my web application with my Google account. When my app is authorized, it receives credentials needed to call desired API. Because I don't want to call for these credentials each time I need to call API, I've created SQLAlchemy models for storing them.

```py
scopes_m2m = db.Table(
    'scopes',
    db.Column(
        'scope_id',
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('oauth2_scopes.id'),
        primary_key=True),
    db.Column(
        'credential_id',
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('oauth2_credentials.id'),
        primary_key=True),
)


class OAuth2Scope(db.Model):
    '''
    Google OAuth2 scope for resource
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'oauth2_scopes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    scope = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def from_scope(cls, scope):
        ''' Create OAuth2Scope model object if not exists

        :param scope: str - scope name
        :return: OAuth2Scope object
        '''
        scopes = {row.scope: row for row in cls.query.all()}
        if not scope in scopes.keys():
            return cls(scope=scope)
        return scopes[scope]


class OAuth2Credential(db.Model):
    '''
    Google OAuth2 credentials for accessing Proximity Beacon API
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'oauth2_credentials'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    token_uri = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    client_id = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    client_secret = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    token = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    refresh_token = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    scopes = db.relationship(
        'OAuth2Scope',
        secondary=scopes_m2m,
        backref=db.backref('credentials', lazy=True),
        lazy='subquery')

    @classmethod
    def from_creds(cls, credentials):
        ''' Create model object from google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials

        :param credentials: google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object
        :return: OAuth2Credential object
        '''
        client_id = credentials.client_id
        scopes = credentials.scopes
        token = credentials.token
        refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token
        client_secret = credentials.client_secret
        token_uri = credentials.token_uri
        oauth2_credential = OAuth2Credential.query.filter_by(
            client_id=client_id).first()
        oauth2_scopes = [OAuth2Scope.from_scope(scope) for scope in scopes]
        if not oauth2_credential:
            oauth2_credential = OAuth2Credential(
                client_id=client_id,
                token_uri=credentials.token_uri,
                client_secret=credentials.client_secret,
                token=credentials.token,
                refresh_token=credentials.refresh_token)
            for oauth2_scope in oauth2_scopes:
                oauth2_credential.scopes.append(oauth2_scope)
        else:
            oauth2_credential.token_uri = token_uri
            oauth2_credential.token = token
            oauth2_credential.refresh_token = refresh_token
            oauth2_credential.client_secret = client_secret
            for oauth2_scope in oauth2_scopes:
                if oauth2_scope in oauth2_credential.scopes:
                    oauth2_credential.scopes.append(oauth2_scope)
        return oauth2_credential

    def get_creds(self):
        ''' Get google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object
        from model's object

        :return: google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object
        '''
        data = {
            'token_uri': self.token_uri,
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'token': self.token,
            'refresh_token': self.refresh_token,
            'scopes': [s.scope for s in self.scopes]
        }
        return Credentials(**data)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'token_uri': self.token_uri,
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'token': self.token,
            'refresh_token': self.refresh_token,
            'scopes': [s.scope for s in self.scopes]
        }
```

It's important to note that each credential stores list of scopes that are links to particular API that my app has granted access to. Because many scopes can be used by many credentials, I've created many-to-many relationship between my scope `OAuth2Scope` model and `OAuth2Credential` model. To create new instance of OAuth2 credentials I call `from_creds` class method of OAuth2Credential` and here is the place where thinks look a little bit complicated:

- First, I'm verifying if credentials already exist in db:

```py
oauth2_credential = OAuth2Credential.query.filter_by(
            client_id=client_id).first()
```

- Then I create list of scope objects based from scopes list provided by `Credentials` object.
- If there is credential with provided `client_id` than I update them (in case there are some changes, for example new scopes are added) if not then I create new `OAuth2Credential` instance.

For me this code looks too complicated because it requires querying data too often which will cause performance issues in the future.

Any suggestions what can be improved here?